# How to use spatial indexes in SQL queries made on geopackages

Tags: sql, geopackage, spatial-index

I'm trying to learn how to write geopackage SQL queries so that the r tree index is used, but I can't seem to find any good information. I'm just trying to write a simple query in the qgis db manager like so:

```
SELECT pts.* 
FROM pts, polys, 
WHERE ST_WITHIN(pts.geom,polys.geom)
```

it takes an extremely long time, but running the same query in qgis using the select by location tool is nearly instant. I figure that the select by location tool must be using a spatial index, while the query is not. I know that spatial indexes must be explicitly included in a geopackage query, but I can not seem to find out how to do so. how do I rewrite this query to use the rtree spatial index?

I am forced by work to use QGIS version 3.12.3 to create and access my geopackages,although running `gdalinfo --version` in the OSGeo4W shell indicates I am using GDAL 3.0.4

Comment: Did you try do run `SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('table_name', 'geom_column_name')`? in the DB Manager then your query again to see if speedup? See also https://medium.com/@wherelytics/understanding-spatial-indexes-in-ogc-geopackage-files-9960fdf71f82 to use index in your SQL query

Comment: I did, no dice. I think it needs to have the spatial index explicitly called to work. in spatialite, for example, the following query runs quite fast.

SELECT points.*
FROM polys, points
WHERE ST_Within(points.geometry, polys.geometry) = 1 AND points.ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID
    FROM SpatialIndex
    WHERE f_table_name = 'points' AND search_frame = polys.geometry
); 

however this syntax does not seem to work in geopackages

Comment: You can find SQL examples with a subquery and JOIN from https://erouault.blogspot.com/2017/03/dealing-with-huge-vector-geopackage.html. I am not sure if the finding about JOIN being faster is true for all use cases.

Answer (score 2):

GeoPackage is using "rtree" as a name of the spatial index. The basic usage with subquery is

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE fid IN 
       (SELECT id FROM the_rtree WHERE 
        xmin <= bbox_xmax AND xmax >= bbox_xmin AND
        ymin <= bboy_ymay AND ymay >= bboy_ymin)
```

Comment: I'd add that the convention for Rtrees in Geopackages seems to be `rtree_thislayer_geom` for layer `thislayer`, and coordinates are labelled as `miny`, `maxy`, `minx` and `maxx`